# how to find unlicensed user with data from different folders to delete in tableau server

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have users who are left the organization and they own content in different folders. Is there any way to find out all the users and all the content they own to change the ownership and then to delete them at once. Please suggest best way to do it with minimal effort.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the username and you'll see all their content.

[image]